# Query de Mysql misma tabla dos filtros recursivos

Tags: mysql

buenas noches. Le escribo para ver si me pueden ayudar con esta consulta que llevo dias no logrando el resultado necesario.

Tengo la siguiente tabla en mysql:

```
id_servicio -> llave primaria
fecha_servicio -> datetime
id_servicio_estado
id_servicio_estado_entrega
```

fecha_servicio -> datetime
    id_empresa

**Ejemplo de datos:**

id_servicio | fecha_servicio | id_servicio_estado |  id_servicio_estado_entrega | id_empresa

```
1, 2005-03-22, 2, 8, 1

1, 2017-03-01, 2, 8, 1

1, 2017-03-18, 2, 7, 1

1, 2017-04-01, 2, 8, 1

1, 2017-10-01, 1, 8, 1
```

**Estoy necesitando tener el siguiente resultado.**

fecha_servicio | id_servicio_estado |  id_servicio_estado_entrega

```
marzo , 2, 1
abril , 1, 1
octubre, 0, 1
```

La consulta debe entregar todos los servicios correspondiente a la empresa =1, donde el año sea = 2017, id_servicio_estado = 2 y id_servicio_estado_entrega = 8, agrupado por mes dentro del mismo año, siendo el resultado ordenado por numero de mes dentro del año. Ejemplo Enero, Febrero, Marzo, etc etc.

La idea es ver como es el query para después poder transformarlo a codeignater.

Agradezo su ayuda al respecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trataba de comprender la consulta que quieres realizar, y creo que esta algo mal explicada a mi parecer, al hacer algunas pruebas en un servidor  mysql con los datos que posteaste pude darme cuenta de ello, lo que entendi segun al resultado que posteaste fue que quieres filtrar los servicios de una empresa(por id_empresa y año servicio) y luego hacer un conteo por mes de los campos id_servicio_estado = 2 y id_servicio_estado_entrega = 8. Si lo que comprendi es correcto, la siguiente consulta pueda servirte de ayuda.

```
 SELECT     
 CASE
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 1 THEN "ENERO"
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 2 THEN "FEBRERO"
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 3 THEN "MARZO"
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 4 THEN "ABRIL"
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 5 THEN "MAYO"
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 6 THEN "JUNIO"
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 7 THEN "JULIO"
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 8 THEN "AGOSTO"
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 9 THEN "SEPTIEMBRE"
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 10 THEN "OCTUBRE"
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 11 THEN "NOVIEMBRE"
     WHEN tabla.mes_servicio = 12 THEN "DICIEMBRE"
 ELSE "ERROR MES"
 END AS 'mes',
 SUM(tabla.id_servicio_estado) AS servicioEntrega2,
 SUM(tabla.id_servicio_estado_entrega) AS servicioEstadoEntrega8

 FROM
 (
     SELECT MONTH(p.fecha_servicio) AS mes_servicio,
     CASE
         WHEN p.id_servicio_estado = 2  THEN 1
         ELSE 0
     END AS 'id_servicio_estado',
     CASE
         WHEN P.id_servicio_estado_entrega = 8 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
     END AS 'id_servicio_estado_entrega'
     FROM prueba p
     WHERE YEAR(p.fecha_servicio) = 2017 AND p.id_empresa = 1

 ) tabla
 GROUP BY tabla.mes_servicio
 ORDER BY tabla.mes_servicio ASC
```

Nota: Hize la prueba con los datos que posteaste, utilize una tabla llamada prueba, para no tener problemas en tu servidor al correr la consulta solo cambia el nombre de la tabla ^_^.

Comment: Hola como estas, si me funciono correctamente.

Comment: Consulta, como seria si es que tengo dos campos de fechas diferentes pero el resultado se siga agrupado por mes.  

Ejemplo:

Tengo fecha_servicio (para el id_servicio_estado = 2) y fecha_servicio_entrega (para el id_servicio_estado_entrega = 8).

Si el id_servicio_estado = 2 y la fecha_servicio por ejemplo... es abril, que sume 1 y en el caso de que fecha_servicio_entrega sea tambien abril, sume otro 1, quedando asi: abril 1 para servicioEntrega2 y 1 para servicioEstadoEntrega8

Comment: Hola, tal vez si agregas algún ejemplo de este ultimo requerimiento que tienes, con los datos que posteaste, podria ayudarte. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un problema con lo que pides, quieres agrupar datos por mes pero estás asumiendo que id_servicio_estado e id_empresa son iguales, no puedes agrupar por mes y sacar esos datos correctamente.

Te facilito una query para que te sirva de guía, seguramente lo que necesites sea algo similar:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(fecha_servicio,"%M"), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(id_servicio_estado), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(id_empresa)
WHERE YEAR(fecha_servicio) = 2017
    AND id_servicio_estado = 2 
    AND id_servicio_estado_entrega = 8
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(fecha_servicio,"%M"), MONTH(fecha_servicio)
ORDER BY MONTH(fecha_servicio);
```